# process launch failed: failed to get the task for process 2847

Tags: ios, xcode

When I use Xcode 7.2.1 and iPad mini 2 for debugging, Xcode shows this message:

```
process launch failed: failed to get the task for process 2847
```

Comment: Are you using development provisioning profile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution 1:** You are Distribution provisioning profile in Development.You need to use a Development provisioning profile if you want the debugger to link to your XCode.

**Solution 2:**
    Go to `Xcode>Preferences>Account Tab>Select Apple ID>View Details>Refresh Button` (Bottom left corner).

Reinitiate Xcode.

May be it will help you.